# drop fin packet with iptables rule

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw

Os is linux mint 19, i want to setup a rule in iptables to drop the incomming FIN packet as a response of the FIN_WAIT_2 state.
This for a given port. I want to test an application and need some connections staying in the FIN_WAIT_2 tcp state.
Firewall is ufw

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to drop the incoming FIN packet when you always initiate the shutdown of the connection, then a rule such as the following should suffice:

```
iptables -I INPUT --protocol tcp --destination-port 1337 --tcp-flags FIN FIN -j DROP
```

However this will mess up closing of connections by the other end of the connection. I don't think that it's possible to only drop the FIN if preceded by an ACK.

Comment: At the client site the connection stays in FIN_WAIT1. This is one of the states i want the client to stay in for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I haven't found any notes about checking the tcp flags in the ufw manual.

In iptables your scenario can be implemented in some complex way using the ipset, but there are some limitations. I guess, your host is the tcp client, and server port number is 1234 (free to change it).

```
# create the ipset list for fin_wait sockets.
# every entry is tuple (local-ip,local-port,remote-ip)
ipset create fin_wait hash:ip,port,ip timeout 3000

# if local host sends the fin packet inside established connection
#   add entry into fin_wait list
iptables -A OUTPUT \
         -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN FIN \
         --dport 1234 \
         -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED \
    -j SET --add-set fin_wait src,src,dst --exist

# if local host receives the fin packet for fin wait socket
#   drop it before tcp stack processing
iptables -A INPUT \
         -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN FIN \
         --sport 1234 \
         -m set --match-set fin_wait dst,dst,src \
    -j DROP
```

For server there is difference.

```
# create list for test clients
ipset create test_clients hash:ip

# add addresses of test clients
ipset add test_clients 192.168.100.10

# create list for clients in fin wait state
# server ip,port is known, so ip,port type is enough
ipset create fin_wait_clients hash:ip,port timeout 3000

# if server receives fin from test client
#     add client's ip,port into set
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp \
         --dport 1234 \
         --tcp-flags FIN FIN \
         -m set --match-set test_clients src \
    -j SET --add-set fin_wait_clients src,src --exist

# if server sends fin to test client as reply
#     block this fin
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp \
         --sport 1234 \
         --tcp-flags FIN FIN \
         -m set --match-set fin_wait_clients dst,dst \
    -j DROP
```

Some notes:

- Use `ipset list fin_wait` command to list the current blocked entries from iptables' point of view
- Use `ss -t4 state fin-wait-2` command to list sockets in fin wait 2 state
- Order of rules is very important.
- Better use the iptables-save / iptables-restore / iptables-apply tools to safety rule set changing.

Comment: i don't see the 'ss -t4 ...' part of the rule, should it be part of the rule? Can you please add a destination port for which the rule is valid?

Comment: `ss -t4 state fin-wait-2` isn't a part of any rule, it's a separate command to list sockets in a host system. Most suitable set type is ip.port,ip, so there isn't way to use full 4-elements tuples and destination port, but you can add the server side port number with adding `--dport <NUM>` / `--sport <NUM>` into `OUTPUT` / `INPUT` rules.

Comment: >>> I guess, your host is the tcp client, and server port number is 1234. I want to apply the rules at the server. So the incomming connection is at port 20000 in this case. I've added the rules but I don't see any blocked entries. Something wrong with INPUT and OUTPUT?

Comment: For server need other rules. I'll edit the answer to provide the rules for server too. I've written rules for client because you asked about client, not server.

Comment: I've got a "bad argument 'test_clients' '" probably because of the line "-m set test_clients src"

Comment: Fixed. I've missed the 'match-set' option in the rules.

Comment: There were no entries in fin_wait_clients after a connection to the server and given port. After I changed -sport to -dport in the OUTPUT rule a entry was created in the fin_wait_clients. However at the client site the connection stayed for a longer period in TIME_WAIT (seen with netstat) and later on all data was sent end the connection closed.

Comment: Entry is added into fin_wait_clients only after client has sent the tcp segment with fin flag and server receives this segment. Also, server side after this stays in LAST ACK state, but client side - in FIN WAIT 2 state.

Comment: for some reason the filter doesn't work, is it possible to add a rule to see the packets dropped for a given destination address? (in /var/log/kern.log or syslog). In a previous filter a check was  done for the ESTABLISHED state, is that removed on purpose?

Comment: Let's try to solve your issue. Can you paste into the question the output of `iptables-save -c`? Are the server and the client on different hosts or on the same?

Comment: client and server are on different hosts. The server listsens on port 20000, iptables rules are applied at the server host. The clients ip address is added to test_clients. I removed the ip address (filled with xxx)  for privacy purposes in the next comment (output of iptables-save -c)

Comment: [2:72] -A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
[2:72] -A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
[2:72] -A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
[0:0] -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20000 --tcp-flags FIN FIN -m set --match-set test_clients src -j SET --add-set fin_wait_clients src,src --exist
[0:0] -A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
[0:0] -A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
[0:0] -A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
[0:0] -A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
[0:0] -A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
[0:0] -A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward

Comment: [2347:2205188] -A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 20000 --tcp-flags FIN FIN -m set --match-set fin_wait_clients dst,dst -j DROP
[0:0] -A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input

Comment: The saved file was to big so the relevant part is split into the INPUT and OUTPUT part.

Comment: Move up the your rules to the top of INPUT / OUTPUT chains. They should be on the first place, not after any ufw rules. As you can see, in the INPUT chain your custom rule has zero counters because the packets are accepted before it.

Comment: That's better. I flushed the iptables and added the rules. In the fin_wait_clients I've got two entries. However at the client side the state is FIN_WAIT1. (Want to have FIN_WAIT2) Shouldn't we drop the ACK sent from the server side? Counters: [9:468] -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20000 --tcp-flags FIN FIN -m set --match-set test_clients src -j SET --add-set fin_wait_clients src,src --exist
[38:2072] -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 20000 --tcp-flags FIN FIN -m set --match-set fin_wait_clients dst,dst -j DROP

Comment: Check the dump. I think server sends replied the ack and the fin in the same tcp packet, so client side will stuck in FIN WAIT 1. There isn't way to fix it with iptables.

Comment: I've made the dump at the client side.From client to server [FIN, ACK] after that from server to client [ACK].
After that a buch of retransmits from client to server [FIN, ACK]

Comment: Yep, it's exactly that behaviour, what you wanted to get.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, much appreciated!!

Comment: Seems like we've misunderstood each other. You're welcome. In lab I've got exactly what you asked and it was working. Check again the TCP fsm diagram.

Comment: What I see that the client stays in FIN_WAIT1, that is also what you 've got in the lab? I'm a little bit confused now...